# spring @autowired NullPointerException from one Controller to another

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I work with Spring and I want to call from one Controller to another Controller.

This is my application-context file

```
<context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.renfe.cme.mybatis,renfe.informes.resumenjornadas" />

    <bean id="resumenMensualJornadasBO" class="renfe.informes.resumenjornadas.ResumenMensualJornadasBO">

    </bean>
```

I call the first Controller from a servlet

```
ResumenMensualJornadasServlet resumenMensualJornadasServlet = new ResumenMensualJornadasServlet();
             resumenMensualJornadasServlet.llamarController(req);
```

This is  ResumenMensualJornadasServlet

```
@Controller
public  class ResumenMensualJornadasServlet 
{
    @Autowired
    private ResumenMensualJornadasBO resumenMensualJornadasBO;
    public void llamarController(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception{
        this.resumenMensualJornadasBO.cargarParametrosInforme(req);

    }
    }
```

ResumenMensualJornadasBO.java is

```
@Component
public class ResumenMensualJornadasBO 
{
    @Autowired
    private ResumenMensualJornadasManager resumenMensualJornadasManager;


    public void cargarParametrosInforme(HttpServletRequest req) throws Exception
    {
        String matricula = StringUtils.recuperarParametro(req, "matricula");
        String fechaDesde = StringUtils.recuperarParametro(req, "fechadesde");
        String fechaHasta = StringUtils.recuperarParametro(req, "fechahasta");

        resumenMensualJornadasManager.obtenerDatos(matricula, fechaDesde, fechaHasta);
    }


}
```

I get NullPointerException when I call

```
this.resumenMensualJornadasBO.cargarParametrosInforme(req);
```

How can I fix the error in @Autowired?

**EDITED**

In the web.xml I have

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:com/renfe/cme/recursos/spring/applicationContext-*.xml</param-value>
        <description>Spring files location</description>
    </context-param>
```

How can I get the bean from this context?

Comment: instead of doing like this `new ResumenMensualJornadasServlet()` you should get it from applicationcontext or simply autowire it

Comment: I can't modify the initial servlet because it is a old project . Can I call to ResumenMensualJornadasServlet without instantiated?

Comment: Can you call `context.getBean()` from `ResumenMensualJornadasServlet` for `ResumenMensualJornadasBO` ? For exampe in some if condition...

Comment: May be you can try adding ResumenMensualJornadasServlet class bean programmatically to Spring Web App Context.

Comment: I would like to ask a question about context. I edited my question